# Cleaning up 3d scanned models

Tags: mesh

I'm scanning real life compositions of my own (just books and things) using an app on my phone called 123D Catch.

Once scanned I have the option of downloading these files in .obj, .3dp and .stl formats.

The files need a lot of cleaning up with a lot of background interference being included in the result and the odd hole needing to be filled in and a base to be put on the scan.

I'm completely new to this software and I'm wondering if there's an easy 'delete' tool where I can delete all the parts of the .stl file on the screen which have shown up around my scan? And also a tool or way of going about (in quite a rudamentary way is fine) filling in a couple of holes which have shown up on the walls of my scan where it hasn't captured completely and also of fitting a base to the model? It just needs to be fit to be sent to the printer and I don't think it is quite yet.

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Comment: For the removing of the other parts, what about going into edit mode, and then separating by loose parts, popping back into object mode, pressing A to select everything, shift+right click on the object you want to keep, and then press X to delete everything else?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you question really has to do with Blender. If you want to clean up a point cloud or a mesh, it is convenient to do in Meshlab. It also has a hole filling tool and surface reconstruction routines, such as Poisson. You also can try CloudCompare.

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode in the mesh menu, there is a mesh cleanup submenu. One of the options is fill holes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might need to try using a repair tool such as https://makeprintable.com/ to automatically repair your file or just like Noidea said meshlab should work as well.